# Python 3.6 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I have written the following code for a chemical reaction kinetics assignment. The problem actually involves rabbits being born and leaving a farm instead of reactions. I'm asked to develop an Explicit Euler method program to model the rabbit population.

My program was running fine (i.e. I wasn't receiving any errors but wasn't getting the results I wanted) until just recently where I've been getting the ValueError (ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.) message. I'm unsure of what I did to my code to prompt the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
def explicit_euler(df, x0, h, n):

    # df - ODE that you wish to solve numerically
    # x0 - initials values for ODE
    # h - step size
    # n - number of steps

    for i in range(0, len(x0)):

        N = np.zeros((len(x0), n))
        t = 0
        N[i, 0] = x0[i]

        for j in range(0, n - 1):

            N[i, j + 1] = N[i, j] + h * df(t, N[i, j])
            t += h

    return N

def df(t, N):

    return [(k2 - k5) * t * N, 
            (k3 - k4) * t * N, 
            (k1 - k2 - k3 - (k6 * N)) * t * N]


N0 = [2., 10., 0.]       # initial number of rabbits [Male, Female, Baby]

# "Reaction rate" coefficients
k1 = 3.5          # [events/rabbits month]
k2 = k3 = 0.15    # [events/rabbits month]
k4 = 0.1          # [events/rabbits month]
k5 = 0.5          # [events/rabbits month]
k6 = 0.1          # [events/rabbits^2 month]

h = 1   # time steps [month]
tspan = 120   # length of time [month]
n = int(tspan / h)   # number of time steps

N = explicit_euler(df, N0, h, n)
t = np.linspace(0, tspan, n)

plot1, = plt.plot(t, N[0, :])
plot2, = plt.plot(t, N[1, :])
plot3, = plt.plot(t, N[2, :])
plt.xlabel('Time [months]')
plt.ylabel('Rabbits')
plt.legend((plot1, plot2, plot3), ('Male', 'Female', 'Babies'))
plt.show()

print(N)
```

EDIT: Forgot to include the error traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d31ce8d859bf> in <module>()
     39 n = int(tspan / h)   # number of time steps
     40 
---> 41 N = explicit_euler(df, N0, h, n)
     42 t = np.linspace(0, tspan, n)
     43 

<ipython-input-4-d31ce8d859bf> in explicit_euler(df, x0, h, n)
     14         for j in range(0, n - 1):
     15 
---> 16             N[i, j + 1] = N[i, j] + h * df(t, N[i, j])
     17             t += h
     18 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Could you post your error traceback?

Comment: Yup! I added it in an edit.

Comment: `h * df(t, N[i, j])` is a list, you can't add it to a scalar and assign it to another scalar

Comment: Okay, that helps a little bit. Excuse my ignorance but I'm unsure of how to move forward. Say i = 0, then I want to use the first element in df, i = 1 for the second, and so on. How would I do that since I can't index a function?

Comment: well actually `df(t, N[i, j])` is not a function anymore, just use `h * df(t, N[i, j])[i]`

Comment: Ah! I thought it would still be considered a function at that point. Thank you!

Comment: btw if you multiply a `list` with an integer it will multiplicate the list other than multiplying the value inside, for `numpy array` you can do the latter. i.e. `2*[1] == [1,1]` and `2*np.array([1]) == np.array([2])`